# std::addressof for the end iterator

Tags: c++

I want to get the address of `first` and `last` iterators so I can converter them to `void` pointers, so I have code that looks like this:

```
class foo {
public:
  template <typename random_access_iterator>
  foo(random_access_iterator first, random_access_iterator last)
    : first_(std::addressof(*first))
    , last_ (std::addressof(*last)
  {}

private:
  const void* first_;
  const void* last_;
};
```

However, when I try to initialize `last_` I can't dereference that iterator. Is there a way I can get the last address without doing some silly hack like

```
last_(first_ + std::distance(first, last))
```

or is that my only option?

Comment: And why do you want the types of those data members to be `void *` instead of `random_access_iterator`?

Comment: You seem to want an address of an element an iterator refers to - but `last` doesn't refer to any element. Which address, exactly, do you expect to obtain?

Comment: There is no possible way to correctly get even the second element of the original range from `first_`.

Comment: `last_(first_ + std::distance(first, last))` ain't gonna work either - you can't index a `void*` pointer. Besides, nothing says those two iterators point into contiguous storage.

Comment: @Praetorian I just wanted to avoid making the entire class a template. And then I ended up experimenting with code and got to this question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I wrote this code snippet quickly those void pointers are actually byte pointers so the address go up by 1. It was just a random question. You made me come to a realization when you stated, "last doesn't refer to any element". That makes a lot of sense why I had confusion. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @Marlon There are too many problems with the `void *` conversion. Random access iterator doesn't mean contiguous in memory (`std::deque`) so you have no way of getting to the intermediate elements using raw pointers. Also, `void *` doesn't carry any size information about the type it's pointing at.

Comment: If you're doing this in order to pass through some kind of callback function, the only safe way is to pass a void* to the iterator. Then you cast and dereference to the iterator, then you dereference that to the object. You can use your iterator then to move forward and back, all following the rules.